# LINQ: How do i select 3 different column values from 3 different tables?

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have three tables `Corevalue`, `SubjectType` and `Question`.

I want  to select `CoreValue.Sname`, `SubjectType.Cname` and `Question.QuestionText`, I know how it works with SQL but not LINQ any help would be appreciated.

Somethng like this in SQL:

```
SELECT 
   CoreValue.Cname, 
   Question.Questiontext, 
   SubjectType.Sname 
FROM 
   Corevalue 
JOIN Question
   ON Corevalue.CID = question.QID 
JOIN SubjecType 
   ON Question.QID = SubjectType.SID;
```

I quess this one is right, but I want to LINQ :/

Thanks on Advance

Best Regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to express the join in SQL too:

```
var query = from core in db.Cores
            join question in db.Questions on core.CID equals question.QID
            join subject in db.Subjects on question.QID equals subject.SID
            select new {
                core.CoreName,
                question.QuestionText,
                subject.SubjectName
            };
```

Of course if you've mapped your database relations, you may not need to perform the join explicitly, preferring simple properties instead - it all depends on how you're using LINQ.

Note that your joins seem slightly odd, in terms of the names of the IDs - it's as if you've really got three entities all using *exactly* the same IDs. I'd expect something more like this:

```
var query = from core in db.Cores
            join question in db.Questions on core.ID equals question.CoreID
            join subject in db.Subjects on core.ID equals subject.CoreID
            select new {
                core.CoreName,
                question.QuestionText,
                subject.SubjectName
            };
```